# how to manage vendor drops in git, especially after modifications have already been made?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

Basically, i want to bring in drops from separate repositories.  There continues to be updates to those repos and we want to eventually bring those updates into git. Anyway, the new repo has some directory restructuring.

This is the methodology used to get the original repo baseline into git:

1. Branch old_repo off of master and checkout
2. Deleted all items
3. Copy over the old repository entirety
4. Then git add all the files and git commit
5. Checked out master and git pull
6. Then git merge -s old_repo

The git status was empty establishing the baseline which is a great start. What are some of the best way to manage vendor drops in git?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process may show empty directories but they are not in git and can be deleted.  Later merges will have new files and will need to be moved to the right place using git move.  To prove the empty directories aren't in git after git merge -s and the final commit, delete everything followed by a hard reset:

```
git fetch origin 
git reset --hard origin/master
```

FYI, below is the entire methodology I'm using.  If someone can point me to a better method for taking "vendor" drops of code, I'll go up vote it.  I believe that is the best model for taking clean drops where we want merge history.

### Strategy

Overview

1. vendor_drops branch built up to store major revisions
2. test_merge branch used to “ours” merge the last merged drop that was unfortunately done manually.  no changes were reported, as expected, since we used "ours"
3. update next series of vendor drops and merge as normal since the baseline is available

Detailed

1. Get the vendor's baseline

   ```
    // clean clean vendor code, no private files git checkout master
    git branch vendor_drops
    git checkout vendor_drops  

    // delete all files    

    // copy over xgp baseline    

    // add all the files, both known and unknown
    git add –u  
    git ls-files -o --exclude-standard -z | while read -r -d '' file;
        do git add "$file";
        echo git add $file;  
    done

    git commit –m “VENDOR DROP v1.2 Merge”
   ```

2a. Since this drop is already in the code, bring it in symbolically for future merges

> ```
>     git checkout master
>     git branch test_merge
>     git checkout test_merge
>     git merge -s ours vendor_drops
> ```

2b. Push the symbolic merge to master (the slow way?)

> ```
>     git checkout master
>     git fetch
>     git pull
>     git merge test_merge
>     git push origin master
> ```

*Note: you may see "ghost" directories which can just be deleted*